# .htaccess php to html

Tags: .htaccess

sorry for this simple question, however i still cant get my head round using .htaccess

I'm trying to convert:

search.php?s=dvd&page=1

to

/Search/dvd/page1.html

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 1):

I think something like:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z]+)/page([0-9]+)\.html$ search.php?$1&page$2
```

Should do the trick.

Further reading here: http://www.webforgers.net/mod-rewrite/mod-rewrite-syntax.php

Answer (score 0):

you must put your link "`/Search/dvd/page1.html`" in the page and with htaccess it will convert to the "`search.php?s=dvd&page=1`" . i hope it be usefull :)

sample correct htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule Search/(\d+)/page?(\d+)\.html$ search.php?s=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: This won't work because RewriteRule only matches REQUEST_URI not the QUERY_STRING

Comment: test it : RewriteRule Search/([A-Za-z]+)/page?(\d+)\.html$ search.php?s=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question OP wants to convert php to html redirection. Try this rule in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

# to match /search.php?s=dvd&page=1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([^&]*)&page=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^search\.php/?$ /Search/%1/page%2.html? [R,L,NC]

# to match /search.php?page=12&s=dvd
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]*)&s=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^search\.php/?$ /Search/%2/page%1.html? [R,L,NC]
```

R=301 will redirect with https status 301

L will make last rule

NC is for no case comparison

%1 and %2 are the query parameter values

Answer (score 0):

I think you want make clean URI, so if user type url like this:

```
search/televisi/page4.html
```

it same as like ***search.php?s=dvd&page=1***

Add this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/([a-z]+)/page([1-9]+).html$ search.php?s=$1&page=$2
```